# How to provide RPS in Jmeter testing?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am new to testing using Jmeter. For now I have created a test plan which creates 1000 threads and the ramp up period is 20 seconds with the loop of 50. I am getting test results. But could you please help me how I can set the RPS so that I can know how many request per second my application can handle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by using [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) at your test plan level.

Constant Throughput timer allows you to maintain the throughput of your server (requests/sec). Constant Throughput Timer is only capable of pausing JMeter threads in order to slow them down to reach the target throughput. Also, it works only on a minute level so you need to properly calculate the ramp-up period and let your test run long enough.

Here are the workarounds:

1. Calculate the number of threads you need to achieve your target throughputs. Formula is:

   > RPS * max response time in second
2. Use the Ramp-up periods for the threads to active accordingly.
3. Make the loop count value to `Forever`
4. Set the test duration accordingly.

As Constant Throughput Timer works on a minute level, to achieve `X` RPS you have to configure your "**Target Throughput**" value to `X*60/min` and "**Calculate Throughput based on**" value as "**All active threads**".

For example, if you need 100 RPS, then "**Target Throughput**" value should be `6000/min` in [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just a quick question. I set the throughput timer to be 18000 which means 300RPS. Number of threads to be 1000 and the rampup is 10 seconds(which just takes 10 seconds to set 1000 threads up right) ...When the target thread is reached, is it guaranteed that the server is filled with 300RPS ? Is there any place to check in Jmeter?

Comment: Yes, you can check it by using the [Hits Per Second Listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HitsPerSecond/) and as well as [Active Threads Over Time Listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/). But it is not guaranteed, because it depends on your application's response time. That's why we need to calculate enough number of threads required for the test first.

Answer (score 2):

In order to determine the delivered load you can generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) which provides `Hits Per Second` chart (and many more)

[image]

If you want to define the desired RPS - the easiest option is going for [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin) combination. You can define the desired throughput in terms of requests per minute/second and given you connect the aforementioned test elements via [Feedback Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Use-With-Throughput-Shaping-Timer-Feedback-Function) JMeter will be able to automatically kick off extra threads to reach/maintain the desired throughput in case if current amount is not enough.

You can install these plugins using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image]