# How I can estimate maximum number of requests per second for J-meter with 8 users

Tags: jmeter-5.0

Scenario is

1. Total Number of Users 50000
2. Ramp up time = 2 Minutes
3. Test Duration = 5 Minutes

while I've login credentials of 8 users

So, Please guide that how I can send 50000 requests in 2 minutes with 8 users

Answer (score 0):

Request per Second (RPS) is a result of your load test execution. You cannot estimate it beforehand.
Typically, you have a number in mind like ex. *15rps* based on your application history or the research you might have done. While you do load test, you assert if actual rps >= expected rps. Accordingly, you can work report your findings to business team / development team.

There are various factors like server configuration, network, think time which can affect your answer. With a lower server config (1 vcpu and 1 gb ram) you can expect a relatively low rps. And this number will improve as you increase server capacity.

Perhaps, follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55294841/how-to-provide-rps-in-jmeter-testing) thread.